# how do I convert a Terraform map variable into a string?

Tags: terraform, terraform-template-file

I'm working on an tf plan what builds a json template and out of a map variable and I'm not quite sure how to use the existing looping, type, list functions to do the work.  I know that I cannot pass lists or map to a data "template_file" so my thought was to build the string in a locals or null resource block and then pass that to the template

## Variable

```
  variable "boostrap_servers" {
    type = map
    default = {
      "env01" : [
        "k01.env01",
        "k02.env01"
      ],
      "env02" : [
        "k01.env02"
      ]
  }
```

## Desired text

```
    "connections": {
      "env01": {
        "properties": {
          "bootstrap.servers": "k01.env01,k02.env01"
        }
      },
      "env02": {
        "properties": {
          "bootstrap.servers": "k01.env02"
        }
      },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may simply use the `jsonencode` function and list comprehension for this:

```
locals {
  connections = jsonencode({
    for cluster, servers in local.bootstrap_servers :
    cluster => {
      properties = {
        "bootstrap.servers" = join(",", servers)
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the following works but there's a better question: why not just use the [jsonencode](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/jsonencode.html) function to build the json

```
locals {
  clusters = [
    for cluster, servers in var.boostrap_servers :
  "{\"${cluster}\":{\"properties\":{\"bootstrap.servers\":\"${join(" ,", servers)}\"}}"]
  connections = join(",", local.clusters)
}
```